# Skipping the InRelease step when apt-get update (and go directly to Release)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt, update, package-management

I've just installed a fresh Xenial on a server box and almost immediately tried to install Docker on it.

The [Docker installation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) says that you have to create a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` file and add just the docker repo source in it:

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main
```

then, just going through the normal `apt-get update & install` process.
This step is usually very easy but on this brand new xenial, the `update` step timeouts all the time:

```
Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-xenial/InRelease  Connection timed out after 120000 milliseconds
```

The important point here is that [Docker tells me](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22182#issuecomment-224320199) that they don't have a `InRelease` repo.
Normally, an `apt-get update` should try the **InRelease** step, not find a signed inline source and should then try the the **Release** source.

My problem is that my brand new Xenial stops there without trying the `Release` source.

How can I force Ubuntu to check the 
`https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-xenial/Release` source instead of `https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-xenial/InRelease` ?

If needed, here is the `uname -a` result:

```
Linux sd-83589 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I had no problem installing other packages (zsh, screen, etc..)

Please feel free to ask me any additional information: I'm way over my knowledge on this so I probably have forgotten something...

Comment: You are getting a Connection Timed Out, not an error indicating that Docker does not have an InRelease repo. You probably have a problem connecting to apt.dockerproject.org on port 443, you should test and fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Law29 I learn that some updates are made with HTTPS when others use HTTP :/

I could check with `curl` that HTTPS request wouldn't reach the server.

Turns out is was my firewall which was not configured to accept port 443 requests...
Adding the right lines solved the problem !
Thanks @Law29 !

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue. The `/etc/apt/apt.conf` causes the problem:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://mirrors.aliyun.com/";
```

After deleting this file, everything is ok now.

---

### Updated

I can also bypass the docker repo by adding another line:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://mirrors.aliyun.com/";
Acquire::http::Proxy::apt.dockerproject.org DIRECT;
```

Comment: Be careful on this, as the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` is used for [local apt configuration](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34666/what-happened-to-etc-apt-apt-conf); so if you delete it, some package won't be updated afterwards.
In your case, it seems that [aliyum.com](https://intl.aliyun.com/) is a cloud service so if you still use their tools, you'll probably need the file back !